# How to position an H1 element under the navbar within the header in next tailwindcss

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a next tailwind css project and have encountered an issue with the positioning of an H1 element within my header component. I want the H1 element to be placed under the navbar but it's currently displaying inside the navbar. I've tried different approaches, including using Flexbox and absolute positioning, but haven't been able to achieve the desired result.

***Navbar Code :***

```
<nav className="fixed  w-full border-b border-gray-200 bg-transparent ">
    <div className="mx-auto flex max-w-screen-xl flex-wrap items-center justify-between p-4">
      <Image src={logo} alt="Logo" width={50} height={50} />
      <div className="flex md:order-2">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="text-md mr-4 rounded-full border border-white bg-transparent px-4 py-2  text-white"
        >
          Get started
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={toggleMenu}
          type="button"
          className="inline-flex h-10 w-10 items-center justify-center  rounded-lg p-2 text-sm text-white hover:bg-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600 md:hidden"
          aria-controls="navbar-sticky"
          aria-expanded={isMenuOpen ? "true" : "false"}
        >
          <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
          <svg
            className="h-5 w-5"
            aria-hidden="true"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 17 14"
          >
            <path
              stroke="currentColor"
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              d="M1 1h15M1 7h15M1 13h15"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`items-center justify-between ${
          isMenuOpen ? "flex" : "hidden"
        } w-full md:order-1 md:flex md:w-auto`}
        id="navbar-sticky"
      >
        <ul className="mt-4 flex flex-col rounded-lg border border-gray-100  p-4 font-medium md:mt-0 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:border-0  md:p-0 ">
          <li>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white   md:p-0 "
            >
              About us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white md:p-0 "
            >
              Why Us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href="#"
              className="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white md:p-0  "
            >
              Team
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

***Header code :***

```
<header className="h-[600px] w-full" style={headerStyle}>
   <Navbar />

   <h1 className="text-white text-4xl">heeey yoo</h1>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider applying `position: sticky; top: 0` to the `<nav>` element via `sticky top-0` classes so that the `<nav>` element still takes up layout space to push the `<h1>` down, but still behave like a `fixed` element:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-950">
  <header class="h-[600px] w-full">
    <nav class="sticky top-0 w-full border-b border-gray-200 bg-transparent ">
      <div class="mx-auto flex max-w-screen-xl flex-wrap items-center justify-between p-4">
        <Image src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="Logo" width="50" height="50" />
        <div class="flex md:order-2">
          <button type="button" class="text-md mr-4 rounded-full border border-white bg-transparent px-4 py-2  text-white">
          Get started
        </button>
          <button type="button" class="inline-flex h-10 w-10 items-center justify-center  rounded-lg p-2 text-sm text-white hover:bg-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600 md:hidden"
            aria-controls="navbar-sticky" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
          <svg
            className="h-5 w-5"
            aria-hidden="true"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 17 14"
          >
            <path
              stroke="currentColor"
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              d="M1 1h15M1 7h15M1 13h15"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="items-center justify-between hidden w-full md:order-1 md:flex md:w-auto" id="navbar-sticky">
          <ul class="mt-4 flex flex-col rounded-lg border border-gray-100  p-4 font-medium md:mt-0 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:border-0  md:p-0 ">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white   md:p-0 ">
              About us
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white md:p-0 ">
              Why Us
            </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white md:p-0  ">
              Team
            </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <h1 class="text-white text-4xl">heeey yoo</h1>
  </header>
</body>
```